# Best way to use BLoC as global state management

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

So I have a BLoC which I need to access globally through my app - `CurrentUserBloc` and its purpose is to hold data of currently logged in user. It can hold some states like `CurrentUserWaiting`, `CurrentUserReady`, `CurrentUserError` etc. Some of them hold `user` instance - like `CurrentUserReady`, and some don't - like `CurrentUserWaiting`. Now I need to access this `user` data in order to send an event to another BLoC. For example I want to post a photo and I need `userId` of currently logged in user to do this. But I can't just use `BlocProvider.of<CurrentUserCubit>(context).state.user` to get user data because some of this bloc's states - like `CurrentUserWaiting` - don't store `user` property and compiler won't take this.

I get around it by creating abstract state class `CurrentUserWithUserInstance` and extending it in states that hold `user` property. Then I just access state like this:

```
final currentState = BlocProvider.of<CurrentUserCubit>(context).state
    as CurrentUserWithUserInstance;
```

Then I get `user` property from this and use it to add event in another BLoC.

I was wondering what would be a better way to do this. I need to access user data in multiple places in the app and I don't know if this is a good approach. I know I could use just one state class with all properties and then change it by `copyWith` method. By that doesn't really seem that good to me.

How do you store and access global state using BLoC?

Comment: hello sir, is this method still relevant for use today?

Comment: @Jsoon Hello, yes, it might work, but I often use something different these days.
You could just put getter inside your Bloc/Cubit class:
`User? get user => state is CurrentUserWithUserInstance ? (state as CurrentUserWithUserInstance).user : null;`
Then you can use it somewhere: `BlocProvider.of<CurrentUserCubit>(context).user` and check if it's null or not, then perform your actions based on that

Comment: @Jsoon You could also add custom function to make this whole casting process simpler:
`T? castOrNull<T>(dynamic object) => object is T ? object : null;`
Then your user getter would look like this:
`User? get user => castOrNull<CurrentUserWithUserInstance>(state)?.user;`